# Android - dynamically create a collection of words with ui like tags

Tags: android, textview

Please see the image in the link.. I am working on creating a user profile..

In the profile I want to display a user's hobbies in the manner described by the image in the link. These hobbies will be populated dynamically in a user profile from backend, so I want each hobby gets style like this and gets added one after other like shown. Is it possible? Please advise..

I am using a RelativeLayout as one of the custom list item. My list is created on the fly inside a fragment.

```
RelativeLayout hobbiesLayout= new RelativeLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(new HobbiesItem(inflater, hobbiesLayout));
```

While creating this list item, I want to populate all the hobbies I get from backend and display it as shown in the image. I think it will be custom textviews added to a layout but not sure.

[image: Expected UI Link]

Comment: I think I have tried to do justice to the hold remarks - Please guide if it still requires improvement. @josh,

Comment: You can inflate a TextView for each hobby item which has a background like the one from your post. You will have to set the layout params and layout rules (toRightOf, etc) programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extending from View, override the onDraw() method. Then you can draw the round rectangles and create text. After that, you just have to instantiate and set you new object as an activity's content view.

But I'm pretty sure there might be a easier way...

Answer (score 0):

There is `Chips` implemented as a **Material design component**:

[image]

Definition: [material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips)

Android lib: [material.io/develop/android/components/chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip)